# SWIFT - Can't set MPMediaPicker delegate

Tags: ios, swift, mpmediapickercontroller

Code:

```
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer 

class WelcomeView: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
var mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController = MPMediaPickerController.self(mediaTypes:MPMediaType.Music)
mediaPicker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = false
mediapicker1 = mediaPicker

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
super.didReceiveMemoryWarning() }

var mediapicker1 = MPMediaPickerController()

@IBAction func selectsong(sender: AnyObject) {
self.presentViewController(mediapicker1, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

the didPickMediaItems is delegate method/ how can i set the delegate to mediapicker? on the web site it writen simply but i tryed it and it doesnt work in swift. and also, after pick the song how to play it?

i used this websites to create it: 
[media picker](http://midhunmp-iostips.blogspot.com.es/2013/05/showing-songs-list-in-ios-using.html)
and some code from official apple Programming Guide about creating the "hello world" music app) to play music from allsongsquery()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate` protocol to your `UIViewController` class:

```
class WelcomeView: UIViewController, MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate {
```

Then you can set the delegate of your `MPMediaPickerController` to `self`:

```
mediaPicker.delegate = self
```